# border-radius isnt working anymore on animated image

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, border

I animated an anchor overlay that spins 360degree and should turn to a circle when hovering. It worked just fine this morning, then I had been working all day on other elements on the site, and now I realized that its not working anymore.

I just spent 2 hours tracking back my changes, but still cant figure out why the hell it wouldnt work. I created the transparent overlay wrapper because of firefox bugs, when hovering over the animated image as a wrapper, the link wouldnt work when clicking.

[This is the link to the website](http://lukasrauen.com)

Im talking about the icon on the top left. When hovering it is just spinning, but not changing the border-radius to 50%. Normally it should do that and then spin back to border-radius 0 in 2sec.

Maybe you got an idea why its not working anymore? Would appreciate any kinds of ideas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-radius` is working, you just have to add `overflow:hidden` to  `.wrap_animation`.

```css
.wrap__animation {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: all 2s;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    top: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation__logo__wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
 }
 
 .navigation__logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #f66437;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #f66437 0%, #f66437 19%, #f4352f 37%, #f66437 37%, #f4352f 56%, #f66539 92%, #f66539 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #f66437), color-stop(19%, #f66437), color-stop(37%, #f4352f), color-stop(37%, #f66437), color-stop(56%, #f4352f), color-stop(92%, #f66539), color-stop(100%, #f66539));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #f66437 0%, #f66437 19%, #f4352f 37%, #f66437 37%, #f4352f 56%, #f66539 92%, #f66539 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #f66437 0%, #f66437 19%, #f4352f 37%, #f66437 37%, #f4352f 56%, #f66539 92%, #f66539 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #f66437 0%, #f66437 19%, #f4352f 37%, #f66437 37%, #f4352f 56%, #f66539 92%, #f66539 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f66437 0%, #f66437 19%, #f4352f 37%, #f66437 37%, #f4352f 56%, #f66539 92%, #f66539 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr= '#f66437', endColorstr='#f66539', GradientType=1 );
    animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    
}

.wrap__animation:hover {
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<a class="page-link wrap__animation" href="index.html" title="home">
          <div class="navigation__logo__wrap">
              <div class="navigation__logo"></div>
          </div>
</a>
```